# Ajax form with wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to implement a simple ajax form with WordPress However I am facing problems doing so any help would be greatly appreciated

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline" action="wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" id="footer-subs">

  <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Your Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email Address" />
  <button type="submit" class="red-btn med-btn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
    jQuery('#footer-subs').submit(ajaxSubmit);

              function ajaxSubmit(){

              var data = jQuery(this).serialize();

              //console.log(newSubsForm);

              jQuery.post(jQuery("#footer-subs").attr("action"),data, function(info) {

                  jQuery('h3.subscbribe-box-text').fadeOut(500,function(){
                  jQuery('h3.subscribe-box-submit').html(info).fadeIn();

                });  

            });

              return false;
              }
```

**Functions.php**

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-gravityFooterSubs', 'the_ajax_gravityFooterSubs', array( 'ajaxurl_gravityFooterSubs' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

function gravityFooterSubs(){
  var_dump("LOL")
  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_gravityFooterSubs', 'gravityFooterSubs');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_gravityFooterSubs', 'gravityFooterSubs');
```

EDIT:: I am getting a success message fade In as '0'

Answer (score 0):

okay so I managed to fix the issue by sending an action method with the data variable.

```
jQuery('#footer-subs').submit(ajaxSubmit);

              function ajaxSubmit(){

          var values =  jQuery(this).serializeArray();

          var data = {'action' : 'gravityFooterSubs', 'values': values};


          console.log(data);

          jQuery.post(jQuery("#footer-subs").attr("action"),data, function(info) {

              jQuery('h3.subscbribe-box-text').fadeOut(500,function(){
              jQuery('h3.subscribe-box-submit').html(info).fadeIn();

            });  

        });

          return false;
          }
```